# Apollo Client wont run state updating hook when results are coming from its cache

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to debug an issue I have in my react app and could use some help. I use apollo-client in my app to get data from a graphql-api. A user can enter a `postalCode` and receives some election-specific data from the api. This works perfectly fine as long as the postalCode isn't the same as some previous one. If it's the same as one of the previous ones, the state wont get updated.

E.g.:

- postalCode: `12345` -> works, state updates
- postalCode: `54321` -> works, state updates
- postalCode: `99999` -> works, state updates
- postalCode: `12345` -> doesn't work, state remains unchanged (in loading state)

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {

  const initialPageState: PageState = {
    loading: true,
    showPostalCodeInputForm: false,
    electionOptions: null,
    city: null,
    error: null,
  };
  const [pageState, setPageState] = useState<PageState>(initialPageState);

  const GET_ELECTION = gql`
    query GetElectionForLocation($postalCode: String) {
      GetElectionForLocation(postalCode: $postalCode) {
        city
        electionOptions {
          id
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const [getElectionFromLocation] = useLazyQuery(GET_ELECTION, {
    // fetch-policy: 'network-only' -> state gets updated when uncommenting this line
    onCompleted({ GetElectionForLocation }: GetElectionForLocationResponse) {
      console.log(GetElectionForLocation);
      setPageState({
        loading: false,
        showPostalCodeInputForm: false,
        city: GetElectionForLocation.city,
        electionOptions: GetElectionForLocation.electionOptions,
        error: null,
      });
    },
    onError(apolloError) {
      console.error(apolloError);
      setPageState({
        ...pageState,
        loading: false,
        city: null,
        electionOptions: null,
        error: apolloError,
      });
    },
  });

  const postalCodeSubmitHandler = (postalCode: string) => {
    setPageState({
      ...pageState,
      loading: true,
      city: null,
      electionOptions: null,
    });

    getElectionFromLocation({
      variables: {
        postalCode,
      },
    });
  };

  return <>some jsx</>;
```

However, since I'm console.logging the results of the query, I can tell the `onCompleted`-handler gets executed (results are getting logged). The only thing in there that doesn't get executed is the `setPageState`-function.

Now here comes the funny part: When I change the `fetch-policy` of apollo-client to `network-only`, the state gets updated as expected. Is that intended behaviour or a bug in apollo-client? I mean, I would love to use the cache here, because the results are always the same for each query with the same postalCode and therefor it's the perfect use case for a cache in my opinion. But it's useless, if my app doesn't get updated with the cached results.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think I just found the answer to my own question. It seems to be a bug in apollo-client: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2177.

I had this issue page open already, but didn't pay much attention to it, since  it's marked as closed. But in fact it isn't...